# Paste CSV or Tab-Delimited data to excel with NO formatting

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm pasting Tab Delimited data from Notepad++ to excel (about 50k rows and 3 columns). No matter how many different ways I try it, Excel wants to convert a cell containing one `"` to the next instance of `"` into one cell content.
For Example, if my data looked like this:

```
"Apple  1.0  Store
Banana  1.3  Store
"Cherry"  2.5  Garden
Watermelon 4.0 Field
```

The excel file looks like this:

```
Apple1.0StoreBanana1.3Store
Cherry  2.5GardenWatermelon4.0Field
```

One way to get around this is to open the file as a CSV in excel, however this leads to Excel formatting the number values to simplified ones using Excel's "General" format. So the data would look like the following:

```
"Apple      1     Store
Banana      1.3   Store
"Cherry"    2.5   Garden
Watermelon  4     Field
```

The data I'm getting is coming from SQL Server Studio so my options for file formats are:

- .CSV
- .Txt (Tab-delimited)
- Copy Pasting from Query results

The solution I'm looking for is to have the data represented in Excel with no excel processing taking place on the quotations, numbers or any other cell contents.

Comment: Don't open the file directly in excel import it and control the data types and file layout.  Open a new excel document: Select Data menu: Select From Text in get External Data section.  Select file to import on step 1 of import wizard select  delimited click next.  Select tab, and change text qualifier {none}  click next set column data types to general, text, text click finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't open the file directly in excel.  Instead import it and control the data types and file layout.

- Open a new excel document:
- Select Data menu:
- Select From Text in get External Data section.
- Select file to import
- On step 1 of import wizard select delimited
- Click next
- Select tab checkbox and change text qualifier to {none}.
- Click next
- Set column data types to general, text, text
- Click finish.

Excel auto imports the data the best it can when you open directly in excel.  You lose flexibility/control when this happens.  better to import and control yourself to get the fine adjustments you're looking for.

You end up with something like this:

[image]

- By treating the numbers like text, the zero's don't get messed up.
- By setting the text qualifier to none, the quotes don't get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening it via Text Import?

- Got to Data tab > From Text (third form left on default)
- You will have window similar to Text To Columns.
- Select correct delimiter, remember to remove the quote sign from TExt Qualifier and mark all columns as text to avoid Excel autoformatting.

**Step 1:**
[image: step 1]

**Step 2:**
[image: step 2]

**Step 3:**
[image: step 3]

Answer (score 0):

EXCEL TIP:  TIME SAVING IN IMPORTING CSV FILES INTO EXCEL:    If u pre-set your Text-To-Columns delimiter parameters correctly in EXCEL (eg specify tabs as the delimiter) and then copy and paste the CSV data, Excel will import the CSV paste directly into the correct columns without u having to going through the Text-To-Columns rigmarole.    This was particularly time saving when i had to import hundreds of bank statements into Excel.

However if your Text-To-Columns delimiters are pre-specified incorrectly as e.g. comma and you are importing tab delimited files then excel will dump all the data into one column, and u will have to go through the time consuming process of converting Text-To-Columns for each statement.

EXCEL LOOKS TO THE EXISTING Text-To-Columns delimiters TO SEE IF IT CAN USE THOSE TO MAKE YOUR LIFE EASIER WHEN PASTING DATA

Hope that tip helps (It saved me several hours)

Comment: Why is this question tagged MySQL?